# Sentiment Analysis code not working throws the following error in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, sentiment-analysis

This is the error I am get `bingSent` when I try to execute the code.
This is the code file.

```
afinSent <- text_df %>%
  inner_join(afin) %>%
  group_by(index = date) %>%
  summarise(sentiment = sum(score))
# Joining, by = "word"
bingSent <- text_df %>%
   inner_join(bing) %>%
   count(index = date, sentiment) %>%
   spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>%
   mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
# Joining, by = "word"
# Error in enc2utf8(col_names(col_labels, sep = sep)) : 
#   argument is not a character vector
```

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18BdDrfrsHLj-FX42awHwxfO9ZvC9gwdg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please include example data required to reproduce the problem in the post itself. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6910411)

Comment: Thank you i was able to solve the problem by myself